# create a wizard installation package

Tags: windows, installation, package

i have the following problem:

1- I have a set of executables that must be installed sequentially
2- I have a vbs that add keys in particular path of registry of windows
3- The vbs must be dynamic and configurable

I need to create one only packet that installs the set of executables and run the vbs. Furthermore tha packet must be dynamic, in sense of changing just the vbs depends upon the user is launching it.

Do you have any suggestion on how to create such a packet and how to interacting with it to change the vbs inside?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a free installer program called [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It is easy to learn and flexible enough to do the additional actions you need (single EXE, embedded installers, external scripts). It does not create Windows Installer, but in this case that's a benefit--embedded installers are kind of a bear in MSI. Highly recommended.